# Is there a way to get Miro to use flash?

Tags: flash, miro

I recently downloaded Miro which I used to use with great satisfaction in Windows, however on Ubuntu, Miro cannot play Flash videos or sites because of Flash compatibility issues. Yet I have Flash installed and working great in other applications.

Is there a way to get it working with Miro?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using both miro 4 and 5 however i  found a fix and believe it will be added to version 6

gksu gedit /usr/share/pyshared/miro/plat/frontends/widgets/application.py

find

`gtk.gdk.threads_init()`

replace with

`gobject.threads_init()`

save close

then

gksu gedit /usr/share/pyshared/miro/plat/frontends/widgets/webkitbrowser.py

find and remove the 4 lines below plus the extra blank line under settings.set_property('enable-plugins', False)

> #this disables all plugins -- Miro has problems with the
>
> # adobe flash plugin and hangs when the plugin loads and starts
>
> #this disables all plugins -- Miro has problems with the
>
> settings.set_property('enable-plugins', False)

remove/save/start miro and now hulu and other flash sites should work through the miro browser

Comment: great, ill check it out and report back, thanks

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and miro v.6. I had this problem! your solution perfectly worked!! Thanks

Comment: Tried solution, does not work in 14.04, MIRO just freezes when selecting flash sites, YOUTUBE, HULU... No solution found yet

Answer (score 1):

Modifying `application.py` and `webkitbrowser.py` worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10 with Miro 4.0.3. I just **commented out** the original lines (#) and added the one new one, instead of removing them completely... just in case.